# Hitting the ball to your opponent when it's going out

Tags: rules, tennis

let's consider a smash, in this case it's more likely to happen this situation. Say, one player was making a smash shot and meanwhile the other player is way behind the baseline, the smash goes way off and hits the opponent before touching the ground, it's obvious that the ball was landing out, but who gets the point in this case?

Comment: The answer below is what you want. For recreational players you could play in good faith that an obvious ball out goes against the player making the shot. To avoid confusion discuss at the beginning of the match

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The player that was hit loses the point. To quote from the [Rules of Tennis](http://www.itftennis.com/media/107013/107013.pdf):

> 24. PLAYER LOSES POINT
>
> [...]
>
> i. The ball in play touches the player or anything that the player is wearing or carrying, except the racket

The ball is still in play until it touches the ground or a permanent fixture, so the player has to get out of the way, just as they would for any other ball going out.